# ole automation date to c# date time picker value

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format, ole-automation

I am fetching some data from the SQL server, and trying to display on Front End C# windows form.

dtpMcAccExp.Text =
 DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(reply.Rows[0]["ExpiryDate"])).AddDays(2).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

here, dtpMcAccExp is a DatTimePicker &
reply is a data table where i get sql query reply.

as i get ExpiryDate an OLE date, and 2 days previous date(as a delphi system use to update it), so have to add 2 days to bring in actual date.

rest all you can understand.

The Problem is..
on some computers, where system date time settings Short Date is "dd/MM/yyyy", it works fine, but in some computers where short date is "M/d/yyyy", it gives an error
"string was not recognized as valid date time .."

so the solution is to change every clients computers short date to "dd/MM/yyyy" where i want my application to run.

Or some other solution, i.e. i can change in my coding.
plz help.
Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

For that, simply you can set the systems Current culture and can run...

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
```

Points :
Also you can set the Culture to "en-GB" for dd/MM/yyy, But the data's while store to database MM/dd/yyy may be the standard date format, and will not make any trouble....